Внедрение файла внутрь скрипта BASH
Требуется внедрить файл внутрь скрипта, чтобы у программы не имелось дополнительных файлов, кроме самого скрипта(test.sh)
У нас имеется скрипт следующего вида:
#!/bin/bash
play sound.mp3
printf "Успех"
Требуется заменить [play sound.mp3] на [play "$HEX_CODE"](заменить переменную названия файла на hex-код этого файла или что-то другое). Прошу не предлагать расположить файл в другой директории или инструменты упаковки. Хотелось бы сделать программу портативной и короссплатформенной

@Jour легко, есть же оператор <<

@eri Дайте пример кода, пожалуйста, где это будет работать

дописать в файл можно всё что угодно. если это shell-скрипт, не забудьте перед дописанными данными вызвать команду exit. что именно вызывает у вас трудности - совершенно неясно.

@aleksandrbarakin там смещения высчитывать.... а нескотлько файлов только в tar - хотя с tar получается интересная задумка - можно из одного файла играть много звуков распаковыввая только нужные в пайп.

@eri чтобы нудными вычислениями не заниматься, можно использовать что-нибудь типа makeself

У меня на канале есть видео с примером возможно поможет https://youtu.be/z4Lq5CdbtWI?si=pFQa1fHf_vUdlcAA решал ту же задачу

Кодируешь файл в аски : можно хекс, но мне по душе base64.
base64 sound.mp3 > sound.mp3.b64

В своем bash скрипте пиши
(base64 -d  | play -t mp3 - ) << EOFSOUND

EOFSOUND

Метка EOFSOUND не должна присутствовать  в закодированном файле. Можно использовать любое слово, но если писать EOF, то скрипт будет понятнее(по буквам EOF хорошо гуглится эта конструкция для новичков). EOF переводится как конец файла. А оператор << указывает что дальше идет встроенный документ до следующей метки.
Переходишь на пустую строчку межжу словами-маркерами EOFSOUND и вставляй содержимое sound.mp3.b64
Получится простыня
(base64 -d  | play -t mp3 - ) << EOFSOUND
//uQZAA....
....
VVVV
EOFSOUND

printf "Успех"

NB. Проверил на play из sox, libsox-fmt-mp3 нужен для проигрывания mp3. Для другого плеера приём выполняется аналогично. ffplay  у меня работает лучше на коротких звуках.

Текст между << EOFSOUND и EOFSOUND  называется  встроенный документ (here document). / (это я скорее для ТС)

@eri Спасибо :)

Можно еще вот так, с предварительным вырезанием муз.файла, архива и т.д. добавленного в конец скрипта, подготовка скрипта с файлом:
cat script.sh sound.mp3 > script_with_sound.sh

Скрипт:
#!/bin/bash

cat $0 | sed '1,/__SOUND__/d; 1,/__SOUND__/d' > sound.mp3
play -t sound.mp3 && printf "Успех"

exit 0

__SOUND__


Так можно запихать только один звук.  Но такую конструкцию можно сочетать с tar

Можно и не один, разделить метками __SOUND1__ ... __SOUND2__ и т.д., потребуется немного больше кода.
